# Where can I find the address of the Linux global mem_map array?

Tags: linux, kernel

My distro (Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS) doesn't seem to export this reference so I can't resolve the address at module load time.  I'm looking for another way to determine the address without a kernel re-compile.

I'm running as a guest under VMware Fusion on a macbook pro.  Kernel is 3.13.0-74-generic.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Use `kallsyms_lookup_name`. It is defined in `linux/kallsyms.h` as

```
unsigned long kallsyms_lookup_name(const char *name);
```

Usage is trivial:

```
struct page *my_mem_map = (struct page*)kallsyms_lookup_name("mem_map");
```

---

`kallsyms_lookup_name` is exported for modules since kernel 2.6.33.

For earlier kernels, or for find several symbols at once, generic function `kallsyms_on_each_symbol` can be used. It iterates over all symbols and calls user-specified function for them.

Comment: Thanks very much.  I get a NULL return from this call.  Checked the sources for my kernel version and the symbol is indeed exported in mm/memory.c but mem_map doesn't show up in /proc/kallsyms.

Comment: Hm, it works for me on kernel 3.11. Symbol `mem_map` is exported if `CONFIG_NEED_MULTIPLE_NODES` configuration option is not set. But searching with `kallsyms_lookup_name` doesn't depend on whether symbol is exported or not.

Comment: Must be me then.  I'm trying to access mem_map in an LKM.  If I reference it directly to be resolved at load time I get an unresolved reference.  The LKM works fine if I transfer data from inside the module.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this answer is too late for you @owenh . I am answering it for people who are looking for the same question about mem_map array. Because so far I can not find any clear answer about why mem_map can not be found. After tracing into how `pte_page` works, I record whatever I learn here.

If you can not find mem_map array, it is possible because the kernel is using virtually contiguous mem_map or the [sparse memory model](https://lwn.net/Articles/134804/) is used, both of which do not have a
physically contiguous mem_map array. Instead, it may have a `vmemmap` or `mem_section` as a starting point to find all the `page struct`. This is decided by these macros (`CONFIG_FLATMEM/DISCONTIGMEM/CONFIG_SPARSEMEM_VMEMMAP/CONFIG_SPARSEMEM`) in `include/asm-generic/memory_model.h`. You can check your kernel compilation config flags using something like

```
sudo cat /boot/config-`uname -r` |grep CONFIG_SPARSEMEM_VMEMMAP
```

In `CONFIG_SPARSEMEM_VMEMMAP` mode, the `page struct` array starts from vmemmap, which is at a fixed location 0xffffea0000000000.

```
#define VMEMMAP_START    _AC(0xffffea0000000000, UL)
#define vmemmap ((struct page *)VMEMMAP_START)
```

While, in `CONFIG_SPARSEMEM` mode, the `page struct` array is managed through an 2-dimensional array called mem_section.

In order to know how kernel uses it, we can learn from how kernel get a `page struct` of a page given a `pte` of a page. This macro is called `pte_page`(in `arch/x86/include/asm/pgtable.h`). It transform the pte into   it `pfn`. Using that `pfn`, it can locate the `page struct` either using vmemmap or mem_section. This is in `include/asm-generic/memory_model.h`.